# Is it possible to use Zend Framework on a platform other than ZendServer/Cloud

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

Title says it all really. The only thing I'd like to add is to say that after initial look at the paid versions of Zend Server, it looks like in terms of cost, I would be losing the advantages of not developing a web/cloud application on Microsoft's expensive Azure platform if I did choose to go with Zend. I like the look of the Zend Framework though and am considering using it on an open source LAMP stack. Or should I go with Symfony / CakePHP on LAMP to keep costs down?

Comment: ZF1/2 are just a php framework. So it will work with any php server. If the required stuff is installed etc.

Comment: Please ask _one question_ at a time. I have answered your actual question (as per the title).  Please avoid open-ended discussion/debate type questions. See the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your (actual, answerable) question is: Yes.

The framework is just a bunch of libraries (just like all frameworks); and you do the following:

1. Go to [the download page](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest).
2. Register (its free), and then download "Zend Framework Full Package".
3. Make sure the files are available to your application, by placing them in a directory to which the user that will execute your scripts (it is normally the same user that run the webserver, for example `www-data`).
4. Follow the [get starting guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/overview.html).

If you like build tools, you can also use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to automatically download ZF2 for you, by following the instructions on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer).